# Office workers get offered extra money to work faster by evil boss

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm struggling to remember much about a film that I can't get out of my head!

Workers are asked to work late (it might be new years eve). They are promised their first office party if they finish the work.

I think they are stuffing letters or invitations.  In one scene, an envelope or box drops off a trolley marked "Australia", then in the new scene, bad things are happening in Australia.

To make them work faster they are offered a million pounds/dollars if they finish on time.

Things get weird and it turns out the boss is the devil, and if the workers complete their work by midnight, the world will end.

They then realise the million doesn't matter as they won't be alive to use it.

They also work out if they find their own invitation/letter and escape with it, they will survive the end of the world.

It's very quirky, and I think its fairly recent.  Not sure if it's supposed to be a comedy, but it came across quirky with dark humour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[End of Days, Inc.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3476464/?ref_=nv_sr_2) *(2015)*

[image]

> A group of laid-off workers bribed into working one last night
>   discover that processing the last of their "inventory" will lead to
>   cataclysmic consequences.

I must confess I haven't seen this movie yet but the key details you mentioned,  **the promised party and the severance payment of $1 million**, are both in the [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9imwU4vzd9Y).

Comment: This has been bugging me for ages, that is the film! Thankyou very much! :)